# why jquery is not working inside my content page

Tags: asp.net

why my jquery functions are not working inside the content page ,
In my master page header i called the jquery function 
Code :

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-ui-1.8.19.custom.min.js"></script>

<link type="text/css" href="css/ui-lightness/jquery-ui-1.8.19.custom.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

and in my content page i am giving values to my datetimepicker

source code :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#<%=TextBox1.ClientID %>").datepicker();


    });
</script>
```

Comment: Do you load jQuery as well? Do you get any errors? Does the element with the ID you provide exist?

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure you include the jQuery library also and not just the jQuery-UI Library

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-version-number.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-ui-1.8.19.custom.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

if you are using ASP.NET 4 you can set ClientIDMode Property,look at [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/34151/ASP-NET-4-0-Client-ID-Feature)

Answer (score 0):

jQuery UI is depends on jQuery, Mean it uses jQuery core library functions

So you need to include like

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jQuery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jQueryUI.js"></script>
```

Also put debugger keyword and see $(document) in quick watch. If you are able to find methods then you have included jQuery. If you able to find $.datepicker() then you included jQuery UI also. 3rd step is check $("#<%=TextBox1.ClientID %>").size() > 0

```
<script type="text/javascript">
debugger;
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#<%=TextBox1.ClientID %>").datepicker();
});
</script>
```